# Visual Studio 2015 code style C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm looking for a Plugin for Visual studio 2015 to check the code style.
For example, class name must start with the capital letter, private variables must start with "_" .
I saw this type of check on Eclipse for Java.
Exists a similar plugin for VS 2015?

Best regards.

Comment: Well, since this question is a bit off topic ill just leave this here as a comment. There are many tools capable of this, FxCop, ReSharper, Stylecop, CodeMaid to name a few. Btw: Common practice is **not** to use `_` as prefix for membernames

Answer (score 1):

Try Resharper. It does what you want and more.

Answer (score 1):

You should install `Resharper(by JetBrains)`. It is useful tool that helps you write clear and readable code.

[Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CodeMaid](http://www.codemaid.net/) as an alternative.

Hope helps,